# Using MySQL CASE to SUM last month and this month totals

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, case

I have a query to generate a list of course names and totals from 2 tables. It works fine but now I'd like to get totals for this month and last month in the same query so I've added a couple of cases. The problem is that the cases are returning empty values.

Here's my query:

```
$Sql = "SELECT t1.coursename, t1.id, SUM(t2.amount) AS total,

CASE 
WHEN YEAR(t2.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(t2.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN SUM(t2.amount)
ELSE 0 END 
AS lastMonthTotal,      

CASE
WHEN YEAR(t2.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND MONTH(t2.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) THEN SUM(t2.amount) 
ELSE 0 END 
AS thisMonthTotal

FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.courseid = t1.courseid
WHERE $pdoCoursesString GROUP BY t1.courseid";
```

Comment: put all these case condition under sum(amount ) and also check for the columns in group by clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should put the CASE statement inside the SUM function.

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e10e2/5

SQL:

Test data:

```
create table t1(courseid int, coursename varchar(10));
create table t2(courseid int, date date, amount int);
insert into t1 values(1,'courseA');
insert into t1 values(2,'courseB');
insert into t2 values(1,'20180211',12);
insert into t2 values(1,'20180111',16);
insert into t2 values(2,'20180101',1);
insert into t2 values(2,'20180201',1);
insert into t2 values(2,'20180101',1);
```

Query:

```
SELECT t1.coursename, t1.courseid, SUM(t2.amount) AS total,
SUM(
  CASE 
  WHEN YEAR(t2.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
  AND MONTH(t2.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
  THEN 
    t2.amount
  ELSE 
    0 
  END
) AS lastmonthtotal,
SUM(
  CASE 
  WHEN YEAR(t2.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) 
  AND MONTH(t2.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
  THEN 
    t2.amount
  ELSE 
    0 
  END
) AS thismonthtotal
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.courseid = t1.courseid
GROUP BY t1.courseid
;
```

Result:

```
| coursename | courseid | total | lastmonthtotal | thismonthtotal |
|------------|----------|-------|----------------|----------------|
|    courseA |        1 |    28 |             16 |             12 |
|    courseB |        2 |     3 |              2 |              1 |
```

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the sql fiddle. This was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(case when {condition} then {field} else 0 end)
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation of how the answer helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Place case inside sum.

SUM(CASE WHEN...)

Answer (score 1):

Put the `CASE` inside the `SUM`, not the other way around.

```
$Sql = "SELECT t1.coursename, t1.id, SUM(t2.amount) AS total,

SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(t2.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(t2.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
         THEN t2.amount
         ELSE 0 END) AS lastMonthTotal,      

SUM(CASE
    WHEN YEAR(t2.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND MONTH(t2.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
    THEN t2.amount 
    ELSE 0 END) AS thisMonthTotal

FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.courseid = t1.courseid
WHERE $pdoCoursesString GROUP BY t1.courseid";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should group by for the same columns with not aggregated  function  in your select clause eg t1.coursename, t1.id 
and use sum (  case... ) eg:

```
$Sql = "SELECT t1.coursename, t1.id, SUM(t2.amount) AS total,

   sum(  CASE 
    WHEN YEAR(t2.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(t2.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN t2.amount
    ELSE 0 END )
    AS lastMonthTotal,      

    sum( CASE
    WHEN YEAR(t2.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND MONTH(t2.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) THEN t2.amount
    ELSE 0 END )
    AS thisMonthTotal
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.courseid = t1.courseid
WHERE $pdoCoursesString 
GROUP BY t1.coursename, t1.id";
```